# I'd like some closure about the synonyms [aws-lambda] and [amazon-lambda]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-process, clean-up

When I do a tag search for "lambda", I get both aws-lambda (x 5196) and amazon-lambda (x 174). The two tags are synonyms. Can something be done about the 174 questions that use "amazon-lambda" so that I instead see aws-lambda x 5370 and amazon-lambda x 0?

Comment: Tags are now merged.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. (Now there's 5326 questions - did you delete any?)

Comment: Nope.... The difference is those that were tagged both. Even though they were already syn'd - prior to that amazon-lambda was a tag on questions - just not obviously visible as it was hidden by the syn.